# Ggplotly with tooltip has problems using geom_rect()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to plot some data in a ggplotly plot. 
The x-axis contains dates. Ggplotly doesn't work well with dates as when I hover over a point, the date is displayed as a number.
I solved this by setting a tooltip like below.

Some sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 29, by = "days")), Amount = seq(-10000, 19000, by = 1000),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The plot:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(x, aes(x = Date, y = Amount, group = 1, text = paste("Date: ", Date, "<br>Amount: ", Amount))) + geom_line() + geom_point() 
     , tooltip = "text")
```

Now I want to use geom_rect() to get some background colors depending on the value of the y-axis. This gives me problems as the rectangles seem to be placed on top of the geom_line(). Also, the rectangles are labeled by ggplotly too, which I don't want either. 
Here is the code I tried (the background coloring works fine when I am not using a custom tooltip, but then the problem with the dates in the labels occurs):

```
ggplotly(ggplot(x, aes(x = Date, y = Amount, group = 1, text = paste("Date: ", Date, "<br>Amount: ", Amount))) + geom_line() + geom_point() 
     +
       geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                     xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                     ymin = 10000, ymax = max(max(x$Amount) + 1000, 11000), fill = "1")) +
       geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                     xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                     ymin = 0, ymax = 10000, fill = "2")) +
       geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                     xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                     ymin = min(min(x$Amount) - 1000, 0), ymax = 0, fill = "3"))
     +
       scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("green", "orange", "red"), 0.2))
     , tooltip = "text")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwTZF.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

The following code results in working geom_rect():

```
ggplotly(ggplot(x, aes(x = Date, y = Amount)) + geom_line() + geom_point() 
     +
       geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                     xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                     ymin = 10000, ymax = max(max(x$Amount) + 1000, 11000), fill = "1")) +
       geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                     xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                     ymin = 0, ymax = 10000, fill = "2")) +
       geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                     xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                     ymin = min(min(x$Amount) - 1000, 0), ymax = 0, fill = "3"))
     +
       scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("green", "orange", "red"), 0.2)))
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyiCq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
ggplotly(ggplot() +
           geom_rect(data = x, aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                         xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                         ymin = 10000, ymax = max(max(x$Amount) + 1000, 11000), fill = "1")) +
           geom_rect(data = x, aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                         xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                         ymin = 0, ymax = 10000, fill = "2")) +
           geom_rect(data = x, aes(xmin = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
                         xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date() + 30),
                         ymin = min(min(x$Amount) - 1000, 0), ymax = 0, fill = "3")) + 
           geom_line(data = x, aes(x = Date, y = Amount, group = 1, text = paste("Date: ", Date, "<br>Amount: ", Amount))) + 
           geom_point(data = x, aes(x = Date, y = Amount, text = paste("Date: ", Date, "<br>Amount: ", Amount))) +
                 scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("green", "orange", "red"), 0.2))
               , tooltip = "text")
```

Comment: If you add `group = 1`  to the geom_line aesthetics it works like inteded. Can you edit that in your answer? 
Anyway a big thank you!

Comment: That's why I asked for you to change it ;), thanks again!